# Postgresql - get closest datetime row relative to given datetime value

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a postgres table with a *unique* datetime field.
I would like to use/create a function that takes as argument a datetime value and returns the row id having the closest datetime relative (but not equal) to the passed datetime value. A second argument could specify *before* or *after* the passed value.

Ideally, some combination of native [datetime functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) could handle this requirement. Otherwise it'll have to be a custom function.

Question: What are methods for querying *relative* datetime over a collection of rows?

Comment: Ted, so what is your question? Why do you create this post if you are "still working"?

Comment: What if there are two records sharing the same datetime value, both at the same side of the desired value?

Comment: @MaksimKolesnikov i added a clearer question.

Comment: @wildplasser the datetime column is unique, so that case is ruled out. but in a more general case, i would return the first result, or all results matching the condition.

Comment: Well: there are three possibilities: 1) naive implmentation with `NOT EXISTS` 2) the same with `MIN()` or `MAX()` in a subquery. 3) a subquery with row_number() and/or lead/lag(). The first two queries will have to be mirrorred to allow for the above/below cases, the third possibly not. (I'm not too sure about the third one)

Comment: Most of these answers are old, [my method works with an index using KNN.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44324058/124486)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select id, passed_ts - ts_column difference
from t
where
    passed_ts > ts_column and positive_interval
    or
    passed_ts < ts_column and not positive_interval
order by abs(extract(epoch from passed_ts - ts_column))
limit 1
```

`passed_ts` is the timestamp parameter and `positive_interval` is a boolean parameter. If true only rows where the timestamp column is lower then the passed timestamp. If false the inverse.

Comment: @ted.strauss Updated with a new fix

Comment: This method won't use an index. It's a bit dated. See my answer for a [newer method using knn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44324058/124486)

Answer (score 1):

use simply -.

Assuming you have a table with attributes Key, Attr and T (timestamp with or without timezone):

```
 you can search with

 select min(T - TimeValue) from Table where (T - TimeValue) > 0;
```

this will give you the main difference. You can combine this value with a join to the same table to get the tuple you are interested in:

```
 select * from (select *, T - TimeValue as diff from Table) as T1 NATURAL JOIN
               ( select min(T - TimeValue) as diff from Table where (T - TimeValue) > 0) as T2;
```

that should do it

--dmg

Answer (score 1):

```
-- test rig
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE lutser
        ( dt timestamp NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        );
-- populate it
INSERT INTO lutser(dt)
SELECT gs
FROM generate_series('2013-04-30', '2013-05-01', '1 min'::interval) gs
        ;
DELETE FROM lutser WHERE random() < 0.9;
```

--

```
-- The query:
WITH xyz AS (
        SELECT dt AS hh
        , LAG (dt) OVER (ORDER by dt ) AS ll
        FROM lutser
        )
SELECT  *
FROM xyz bb
WHERE '2013-04-30 12:00' BETWEEN bb.ll AND bb.hh
        ;
```

Result:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to table tmp.lutser
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "lutser_pkey" for table "lutser"
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1441
DELETE 1288
         hh          |         ll          
---------------------+---------------------
 2013-04-30 12:02:00 | 2013-04-30 11:50:00
(1 row)
```

*Wrapping it into a function is left as an excercise for the reader*

UPDATE: here is a second one with the sandwiched-not-exists-trick (TM):

```
SELECT lo.dt AS ll
FROM lutser lo
JOIN lutser hi ON hi.dt > lo.dt
        AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM lutser nx
        WHERE nx.dt < hi.dt
        AND nx.dt > lo.dt
        )
WHERE '2013-04-30 12:00' BETWEEN lo.dt AND hi.dt
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the first row of a select statement producing all the rows below (or above) the given datetime in descending (or ascending) order.

Pseudo code for the function body:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE IF(@above, datecol < @param, datecol > @param)
ORDER BY IF (@above. datecol ASC, datecol DESC)
LIMIT 1
```

However, this does not work: one cannot condition the ordering direction.

The second idea is to do both queries, and select afterwards:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    (
    SELECT 'below' AS dir, id
    FROM table
    WHERE datecol < @param
    ORDER BY datecol DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ) UNION (
    SELECT 'above' AS dir, id
    FROM table
    WHERE datecol > @param
    ORDER BY datecol ASC
    LIMIT 1)
 ) AS t
 WHERE dir = @dir
```

That should be pretty fast with an index on the datetime column.

Comment: I think that the principle of finding the first higher and first lower records separately is probably the best performing where there are very large data sets, but I think you'd need another level of query to identify which of the two is then the closest. Come to think of it, with the first query in a common table expression you could then filter in the second to only return rows closer to the date than that first found row was, which could be a shade more efficient.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Thank you for your advice: I did not understand OP question as matching the absolutely closest row (although I probably should have), because of the second parameter. I don't know how cte are processed, so I decided to go without. If they are really some kind of macro which are replicated at each use site, then it makes sense to use them there (and thinking about it, if one can apply a where clause to a cte at use site, then it is probably working the right way).

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the table to itself with the where condition looking for the smallest nonzero (negative or positive) interval between the base table row's datetime and the joined table row's datetime.  It would be good to have an index on that datetime column.

P.S. You could also look for the max() of the previous or the min() of the subsequent.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE (dt_time > argument_time and search_above = 'true')
   OR (dt_time < argument_time and search_above = 'false')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN search_above = 'true' 
              THEN dt_time - argument_time
              ELSE argument_time - dt_time
         END
LIMIT 1;
```