# PostgreSQL return exact or closest date to queried date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following postgresql syntax that returns values WHERE session_date matches $date_string

Problem is that sometimes the $date_string will not be available in the table, so I am looking to return the closest date to the $date_string

```
$date_string = '2014-04-25';

SELECT year, session_date FROM calendar_dates WHERE session_date='$date_string'
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: See [my method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44323968/124486) for doing this with an index using knn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql - get closest datetime row relative to given datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321741/postgresql-get-closest-datetime-row-relative-to-given-datetime-value)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you want the closest date before, do it this way:

```
SELECT year, session_date
FROM calendar_dates
WHERE session_date < '$date_string'
ORDER BY session_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The closest date after uses similar logic.

For the closest on either side:

```
SELECT year, session_date
FROM calendar_dates
ORDER BY abs(session_date - date '$date_string') 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: is this race condition proof?

Comment: @Zanko . . . As much as any query is.  This is not modifying the data, so it depends on the transaction semantics of any data modification steps going on.

Comment: If you want to get the data for a particular date if available OR if that date is not available, get the closest date before/after, you should replace the `<` operator with `<=` for the closest before date or `>` with `>=` for the closest after date.

Answer (score 19):

## Using [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) and knn

Using this method you can find the nearest event with an index.

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE TABLE foo ( id serial, ts timestamp );

INSERT INTO foo (ts)
VALUES
  ('2017-06-02 03:09'),
  ('2016-06-02 03:09'),
  ('1900-06-02 03:09'),
  ('1954-06-02 03:09');

CREATE INDEX ON foo USING gist(ts);

SELECT *
FROM foo
ORDER BY '1950-06-02 03:09' <-> ts
LIMIT 1;
```

## Pg 11

Coming some time in the distant future... with [knn/btree](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/ce35e97b-cf34-3f5d-6b99-2c25bae49999@postgrespro.ru#ce35e97b-cf34-3f5d-6b99-2c25bae49999@postgrespro.ru)

Comment: How does this compare in speed to the accepted answer? This answer requires creating an index, whereas the accepted answer does not, so I assume there must be an advantage to this answer's approach.

Comment: @runeks grossly faster. And done entirely on an index in PG11+ if indexed.

Comment: would you mind adding this to your answer? Without this information in your answer there's no reason to choose it over the already-accepted answer. Also, can you quantity "grossly faster"? E.g. is it `O(log n)` versus the accepted answer's `O(n)`?

Comment: @runeks before it was O(N) on the table `abs(session_date - date '$date_string')` with this it's `O(N)` **on the index** of the table. They're both scans.

Comment: Very nice. Just tested it on PG 13 and it still works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I found in PG15 I needed to use something like (adjust it for your `$date_string`):

```sql
ORDER BY abs(extract(epoch from (session_date - now())));
```