# (Postgre)SQL - join by most recent date <= another date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join

Given two tables like this

```
 ; table foo
 fk     date
 --     ----
 1      2017-01-01 02:00:00
 2      2017-01-01 04:00:00
 3      2017-01-01 06:00:00

 ; table bar
 fk     date
 --     ----
 1      2017-01-01 02:05:00
 7      2017-01-01 02:20:00
 8      2017-01-01 03:57:00
 21     2017-01-01 06:51:00
 87     2017-01-21 12:00:00
```

how do I write a join that maps each row of table 'bar' to the row of table 'foo' with the most recent timestamp that is less than or equal to the timestamp in 'bar'?  In other words, the desired result is

```
 bar.fk   foo.fk
 ------   ------
 1        1
 7        1
 8        1
 21       3
 87       3
```

This is closely related to, but not the same as, [Postgresql - get closest datetime row relative to given datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321741/postgresql-get-closest-datetime-row-relative-to-given-datetime-value) : that addresses a query for a single row, I need to do a join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a lateral join:

```
select b.*, f.fk
from bar b left join lateral
     (select f.*
      from foo f
      where f.date <= bar.date
      order by f.date desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) f
     on true;
```

You can also do this with a correlated subquery.  The advantage of the lateral join (in this case) is the ability to return multiple columns.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks, I would never have thought of LATERAL, I was flailing around with window functions and getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Without a join:

```
select b.fk,
  (select f.fk from foo f where date = (
      select max(date) from foo where date <= b.date
    )
  ) fk
from bar b
```

or with a join:

```
select b.fk, f.fk
from bar b inner join foo f
on f.date = (select max(date) from foo where date <= b.date)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=9d83063388b7d9062ea45e87bf278952)
Results

```
fk | fk
-------  
 1 |  1
 7 |  1
 8 |  1
21 |  3
87 |  3
```